# Thread was being aborted - C# using queue

Tags: c#, queue, box-api

We have implemented a queue for uploading files to box.net. 
All files are uploaded successfully. but,I am getting the following exception 1 or 2 times in a week. I couldn't found any cause for this exception.

Exception-Message:

> Thread was being aborted.

Exception-Source:

> mscorlib

Exception-StackTrace:

> at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Boolean exitContext, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Object obj)
>   at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(Object obj, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
>   at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(Object obj)
>   at Box.netAPIWebApp.Service.BoxService.monitorOnUploadQueue() in C:\Project\BackupProjects\BoxNetFileUpload\Box.netAPIWebApp\Source\Service\BoxService.cs:line 90

Can any one help on this?

```
private static readonly BoxService instance = new BoxService();

private Queue<FileCabinetUploadHistory> uploadQueue = new Queue<FileCabinetUploadHistory>();


private BoxService()
{
    Thread monitorThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(monitorOnUploadQueue));
    monitorThread.Start();
}

private FileCabinetUploadHistory RemoveFromUploadQueue()
{
    lock (uploadQueue)
    {
        return uploadQueue.Dequeue();
    }
}

private void monitorOnUploadQueue()
{
    FileCabinetUploadHistory fileCabinetUploadHistory = null;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (uploadQueue.Count < 1)
            {
                lock (uploadQueue)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(uploadQueue);
                }
            }
            fileCabinetUploadHistory = uploadQueue.Peek();

            if (fileCabinetUploadHistory != null)
            {
                StartFileUpload(fileCabinetUploadHistory);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        log.Error("Error:--> Class name: BoxService, Method name: monitorOnUploadQueue() \n", exception);
    }
}

public void AddToUploadQueue(FileCabinetUploadHistory fileCabinetUploadHistory)
{
    lock (uploadQueue)
    {
        if (!uploadQueue.Contains(fileCabinetUploadHistory))
        {
            uploadQueue.Enqueue(fileCabinetUploadHistory);
            Monitor.Pulse(uploadQueue);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the source code where this  exception is raised?

Comment: How do you use the `BoxService.monitorOnUploadQueue`?

Comment: @user743414 posting code from BoxService class which throws exception.

Comment: Did you know how many Items are in your queue when you get this error? When and how often is RemoveFromUploadQueue called?

Comment: There was no item in queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it.
ThreadAbortException occurs when Application pool recycles after every 29 hours.

Answer (score 6):

Basically a ThreadAbortException means exactly that: Your thread received an external signal to kill itself. Now ThreadAbortException is a bit special because it can not be handled. It just keeps on terminating your thread by rethrowing itself every time you catch it. See http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/ for details.

So now you probably ask yourself who sent the external signal mentioned above. I don't know. The code you showed does not suffice to say. But there is a very good chance that someone still has a handle of the monitorThread and calls thread.Abort() on it. Does your codebase contain `.Abort()`? If so rest assured that it's a very bad idea. Again see the above link for details.

If you absolutely have to terminate a thread that is waiting on a monitor there are better ways. For example make the thread wait on multiple monitors at the same time: One for the queue and one to signal for termination. Then instead of killing the thread by abort you just pulse the termination monitor and let the thread shut itself down.

By the way, you are accessing your queue in an unsafe way. Write access seems to be under lock condition but read access (Count, Peek) is not. This is not the way locking is supposed to be used and bad things can (and eventually will) happen. Don't do it! See http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/ to find out why.